# On $p$-adic power series

Tags: number-theory, power-series, p-adic-number-theory

I'm stuck in a sentence made by Dwork in his book "An introduction to $G$-functions": Let $b$ a positive real number, define the following set
$$\mathcal{G}(b)=\left\{f(X): \begin{array}{c}
f(X)\in1+X\mathbb{C}_{p}[\![X]\!]\\
f \text{ converges for ord }x>-b\\
|f(x)-1|<1
\end{array}
\right\}$$
(where $1+X\mathbb{C}_{p}[\![X]\!]$ means that $f(0)=1$, and $\text{ord}$ is the additive $p$-adic valuation ), then he says: if $f(X)=1+a_{1}X+a_{2}X^{2}+\cdots\in\mathbb{C}_{p}[\![X]\!]$, then $f(X)\in\mathcal{G}(b)$ if and only if $\text{ord }a_{j}\geq jb$ for every $j\geq 1$.

I have the converse, but I'm stuck dealing with the "if" direction ($\Rightarrow$). I tried arguing by contradiction supposing that there is $j$ for which $\text{ord }a_{j}<jb$ and taking the minimal $j$ with this property I tried to use the strong triangle inequality to get a contradiction with the third property of the set $\mathcal{G}(b)$, but these involves $x$ in the radius of convergence, not on the boundary.

I will appreciate any hint, thanks.

Comment: If $f(p^r x) $ converges for $v(x) \ge 0$ then for $x \in O_{\Bbb{C}_p}$, for all but finitely many values of $x \bmod \mathfrak{m}$, $v(f(p^r x)) = \inf_n v(a_n)+ rn$.

Comment: You’re hoping to show that if $\text{ord}a_j\ge jb$ (all $j$), then $f\in\mathcal G(b)$ ? Which aspect of the definition of $\mathcal G$ is eluding you?

Comment: I'm trying to prove that if $f\in\mathcal{G}(b)$, then $\text{ord }a_{j}\geq jb$ for all $j$. The other direction its done. A couple hours ago I was thinking as follow: For the third condition of the set $\mathcal{G}$ it follows that $\text{ord }a_{j}+j\text{ord }x>0$ for all $j$, then $\frac{\text{ord }a_{j}}{-j}<\text{ord }x$ for all $j$, but by convergence (second property of $\mathcal{G}$) one has $\frac{\text{ord }a_{j}}{-j}\leq -b$ for all $j$, hence $\text{ord }a_{j}\geq jb$ for all $j$. I think this argument works, or I'm missing something?

Comment: I don’t see any reason to say that $\text{ord}\,a_j+j\text{ord}\,x>0$ for all $j$. Of course $\text{ord}\,a_j+j\text{ord}\,x\to+\infty$, but maybe a few are negative?I think I have a proof that involves drawing Newton Polygons, and if you’d like to see it, I’ll give it as an Answer. (maybe not till tomorrow)

Comment: By the third condition we have $\text{ord}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}x^{i}\right)>0$; if there is some $j$ such that $\text{ord }a_{j}+j\text{ord }x<0$ we can take $j$ to be minimal with this property, and by the strong triangle inequality we would have $\text{ord }\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}x^{i}\right)=\text{ord }a_{j}+j\text{ord }x<0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Dear Lubin, it would be nice to my eyes such proof, I was thinking on Newton polygons too, but in my mind approach I need to consider the cases when I have a finite number of sides and separetely an infinite number of sides, and we know that the supremum of the slopes determines the radius of convergence, but I haven't  tried yet

Comment: Ah, but maybe there are, in your series, two or more terms with the same minimum value? Then the value of the sum of these two could well be much higher !

Comment: About a Newton Polygon proof, I’m just too tired tonight to write it out, but maybe tomorrow. (I’m glad you know the relationship between the supremum of the slopes and the radius of convergence — this will make my argument much easier.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right let me make a stab at this. I’m going to use the notation $v(x)$ for the (additive) valuation of $x$, rather than $\text{ord}(x)$, just for convenience of typing, and look at a function $f\in\mathcal G(b)$, $f=1+\sum_1^\infty a_jX^j$.
[image: a Newton-space diagram]

Start with the line $y=bx$, above which we hope all Newton points $(j,v(a_j))$ lie. If not, there is a line $y=\beta x$ through the origin that contains only finitely many Newton points, with no such points below the line. To see this, look at any suspect Newton point $(j_0,j_0\alpha)$ below $y=bx$ (so with $\alpha<b$), and see that there are at most finitely many points drawn below the line $y=\alpha x$. (Otherwise, the domain of convergence would be smaller than we want.)

Now we have our (orange) line $y=\beta x$, $\beta\in\Bbb Q$, with finitely many Newton points on it, and we call the rightmost of these $P=(n,v(a_n))=(n,n\beta)$. Now draw through $P$ a (blue, dashed) line of slope $\beta'\in\Bbb Q$ with $\beta<\beta'<b$, $y=\beta'x+c$, in such a way that all other Newton points lie *above* the line. Again, the existence of such a line is a little delicate for points to the right, but I think the fact that when $v(\xi)=-\beta>-b$ the series $f(\xi)$ is convergent, should take care of that.

Now we’re pretty much done. When you try $\xi\in\Bbb C_p$ with $v(\xi)=-\beta'>-b$, you see that the series is convergent, and all other monomials in the series other than $\xi^na_n$ have value $c=-n\beta'+v(a_n)$, so that the value of the whole series $f(\xi)$ is therefore $c<0$, contradicting the third condition for membership in $\mathcal G(b)$.

And I guess I should say that the argument would have been immeasurably easier if I had allowed myself to use the theory of the Newton copolygon, but I’m uncertain how many of our readers would have been familiar with that.

Comment: Thank you for take your time!! I appreciate very much. I'll read many times in order to understand, since in my first reading that wasn't clear. Also, where can I find some information about Newton copolygons?, it sounds very interesting. A few months in other post you mentioned that and I tried to search about it, but I had bad lucky.

Comment: I don’t know, other than a paper of mine in Journal of Number Theory, 133 (2013), 983–999. I think it’s all in the Appendix there, at the end. (You’ll have to modify some things for your purposes.) If the journal is not available to you, you can e-mail me, and I’ll send you a .pdf